# How to read arrays from file in C#

Tags: c#

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

I have a array which located in the file , how can I read it using C sharp?

Comment: That depends on the format in which it is stored. Can you provide more details?

Comment: http://www.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&rm=202557&rd=6534&pm=4019&cr=10574855
 have details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would probably use a different format, but...

```
using ( Stream stream = new FileStream( @"C:\foo.txt", FileMode.Open ) )
using ( TextReader reader = new StreamReader( stream ) )
{
    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd( );
    contents = contents.Replace( "{", "" ).Replace( "}", "" );
    var values = new List<int>();
    foreach ( string s in contents.Split( ',' ) )
    {
        try
        {
            values.Add( int.Parse( s ) );
        }
        catch ( FormatException fe )
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch ( OverflowException oe )
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you would be more intelligent depending on your situation, but in general this is what you need to do.

Comment: @Ed.. how to change the result into an array with int value?

Comment: You just need to call int.parse (or int.TryParse if you don't feel like using exceptions) to convert each element in 'value' and store it in another array.

Comment: Like ccook pointed out, this is a very general and quickly mocked up solution.  It will most likely require some tweaking on your end.

Answer (score 4):

Read the line into a string. Lose the curlies, split on commas, cast each token into an integer and append it to a List.
Finally use ToArray() to get back an int[]

Look at the `System.IO.File` and `System.String` type documentation in MSDN. You should find members to help you accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex and LINQ to pull a nice one liner:

```
List<int> data = Regex.Matches( 
    File.ReadAllText("data.txt"),
    @"(\d+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Enlightening use of LINQ. I still dont think in LINQ

Comment: Thank you.  It's still not quite as nice as Fortran's file reading though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking up the [String.Split(char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method.

It allows you to take a string and split it into an array of strings based on the characters you pass in (in your case ", ").  For the first element in the array you'd need to remove the { and for the last element, remove the }.  There is a String.Remove() method for this.

Finally you will need to convert each string into an integer.  You can do this with a for each loop and int.TryParse()

TryParse will let you know if it is actually an integer or not, it's good practice to never assume your input is valid.  You're program shouldn't crash because it reads in some bad data.

To actually open the file and read the text, look up StreamReader/File.ReadAllText

Answer (score 0):

Your sample file makes me think JSON. If that's the case, then [JSON.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) could be an effective option.

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer depends on a lot of things, but it sounds like these are you the steps you need to figure out:

- read in the file
- split the contents into pieces
- cast, convert or parse pieces into desired datatype
- add to desired resulting collection

As for how to specifically do each of these, I suspect you can find many resources here on SO and in other locations to find the details. But you're probably looking for a `StreamReader`, `String.Split`, `Int32.Parse` and a `List<int>`.